# Pivoting roles into a single row in SQL Server not returning the correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following view in SQL Server 2012; the screenshot is showing how a single customer has multiple phones and account numbers resulting in multiple rows

[image]

```
SELECT        
    dbo.CustomerModels.CustomerID, dbo.CustomerModels.FirstName,     
    dbo.CustomerModels.Gender, dbo.CustomerModels.AccountsCount, 
    dbo.CustomerModels.PhoneNumbersCount, 
    dbo.CustomerAccountModels.CustomAccountFieldValue,  
    dbo.CustomerPhoneNumberModels.CustomPhoneFieldValue, 
    dbo.AgencyModels.AgencyName, dbo.AgencyModels.AgencyCode
FROM 
    dbo.CustomerModels 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CustomerAccountModels ON dbo.CustomerModels.CustomerID =   dbo.CustomerAccountModels.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CustomerPhoneNumberModels ON dbo.CustomerModels.CustomerID = dbo.CustomerPhoneNumberModels.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AgencyModels ON dbo.CustomerModels.AgencyID = dbo.AgencyModels.AgencyID
```

Now I want to display the results so they shown in the screenshot below instead of the earlier screenshot.

After transposing, the results is showing alright in a columnar form but then instead of the different account numbers and phone numbers showing under separate column, it is the same numbers under different column

[image]

The below shows my code for transposing the query

```
select 
    --CustomerID, 
    max([FirstName]) as [Full Name], 
    max([GenderSex]) AS [Sex], 
    max([AccountsCount]) as [No. Of Accounts], 
    --max([PhoneNumbersCount]) as [Total Fone No],
    max([CustomAccountFieldValue]) as [Account 1],
    --max([CustomAccountFieldValue]) as [Account 2],
    --max([CustomAccountFieldValue]) as [Account 3],
    --max([CustomAccountFieldValue]) as [Account 4],
    --max([CustomAccountFieldValue]) as [Account 5],
    max([CustomPhoneFieldValue]) as [Phone No 1], 
    max([CustomPhoneFieldValue]) as [Phone No. 2],
    max([CustomPhoneFieldValue]) as [Phone No. 3],
    max([CustomPhoneFieldValue]) as [Phone No. 4],
    max([CustomPhoneFieldValue]) as [Phone No. 5],
    max([AgencyName]) as [Agency], 
    max([AgencyCode]) as [Agency Code]
    -- and so on for the remaining columns...
from 
    (select 
         CustomerID, FirstName, Gender, 
       (CASE WHEN Gender = 0 THEN 'Female' WHEN Gender = 1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Other' END) As [GenderSex], 
       AccountsCount, PhoneNumbersCount, 
       CustomAccountFieldValue, 
       CustomPhoneFieldValue, AgencyName, AgencyCode
       , t = concat('CustomAccountFieldValue ',row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by CustomerID)) 
       , c = concat('CustomPhoneFieldValue ',row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by CustomerID)) 
    from SMSAlerts.dbo.ViewAllCustomers
    ) src
pivot (count(CustomerID) for t in ([Account 1],[Account 2],[Account 3], [Account 4], [Account 5]) )pt
pivot (max(PhoneNumbersCount)   for c in ([Phone No. 1],[Phone No. 2],[Phone No. 3],[Phone No. 4],[Phone No. 5]))pc
group by FirstName;
```

Please help on this direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: still waiting for your answers, please members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for several hours without the usual prompt response from members, I was also making a serious research into achieving the desired results. Gracefully I have been able go through some tutorials from [Rolling up multiple roles into a single row in SQL data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/) to achieve my desired results.

```
SELECT
```

CustomerID,
   FirstName,
   AgencyName,
   Gender = (CASE Gender WHEN 0 THEN 'Female' WHEN 1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Other'END),
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + tblAccount.CustomAccountFieldValue
    FROM CustomerAccountModels AS tblAccount
    WHERE tblAccount.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Account Nos],

```
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + tblPhone.CustomPhoneFieldValue
FROM CustomerPhoneNumberModels AS tblPhone
WHERE tblPhone.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Phone Nos]
```

FROM CustomerModels AS tblCustomer INNER JOIN AgencyModels AS tblAgency ON tblCustomer.AgencyID = tblAgency.AgencyID
GROUP BY tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblCustomer.FirstName, tblCustomer.Gender, tblAgency.AgencyName

[The desired result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwkXZ.png)

Comment: Thanks to Almighty God for the wisdom